# SQLServerCE DefaultConnectionFactory

Tags: sql-server-ce, connection-string

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 and try to connect to a new SQLServerCE 4.0 database inside an MVC Web application.
I am using this code

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", "|DataDirectory|", "test.sdf");
```

And it raises this exception :

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 86.

What's wrong with this code?

If I use

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0")
```

It works and creates a database with a very long name matching my assembly name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little late, but this should help:

```
new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", 
    "", @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test.sdf");
```

Comment: Thank you.
It is never late...
I tried your suggestion and I get the same error: 
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 71

Comment: For what it's worth - it is very important to remember to @ prefix the string or use a double backslash. I made that silly mistake and was getting tripped up with the same error.