# Dynamic SQL CE 4 Connection String With DbContext Still getting error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, connection-string, dbcontext

I'm trying to Develop Application that connect to both sql server and Sql CE4.
I create an option to manage sql Ce 4.0 Connection string

```
public partial class ModelContainer : DbContext
{

    public ModelContainer()
    {

            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=D:\\Charities.sdf");
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = con.ConnectionString;
            this.Database.Connection.Open();    
    }
    public DbSet<Grant> Grants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GrantDetail> GrantDetails { get; set; }}
```

but still getting error when connection try to open

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I manged to create another sql server connection in the same way with SqlConnection and it worked but this wont!!

any suggestions?

Best Regards.

Comment: what is the password of your database? your connection string should be like Data Source=D:\\Charities.sdf; Password = 'pwd'

Comment: See the reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905076/sqlserverce-defaultconnectionfactory

Comment: Thank you ErikEj:
I found it here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490190/ef-5-sql-ce-4-how-to-specify-custom-location-for-database-file
it's the same Idia of yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490190/ef-5-sql-ce-4-how-to-specify-custom-location-for-database-file) 
the key is  `Database.DefaultConnectionFactory`  property in Database Class